# Response data is different from the one sent from the graphql server

Tags: javascript, graphql, request

Response data is different from the one sent from the graphql server.

Category page

```
class Category extends React.Component{

    state = {
        data: null,
        error: false,
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { category } = this.props.params

         try {
            const { data } = await client.query({
                query: categoryQuery,
                variables: {
                title: category
               }
            })
            console.log(data)
            this.setState({ data: data.category })

        } catch (err) {
            this.setState({ error: true })
        }

    }

}
```

Here's what categoryQuery looks like >

```
export const categoryQuery = gql`
query CATEGORIES($title: String!) {
  category(input: { title: $title }) {
    name
    products {
      id
      name
      inStock
      gallery
      brand
      attributes {
        id
        name
        type
        items {
          displayValue
          value
          id
        }
      }
      prices {
        amount
        currency {
          symbol
          label
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

The response object looks like this >

```
{
 "category": {
   "name":"all",
   "products":[...]
 }
}
```

When I did console.log(data) in Category Page when componentDidMount it logs the following object. Every product's data is correct but the product of id "apple-imac-2021" is getting the wrong attribute. The server is sending the following attribute

```
"attributes": [
      {
        "id": "Capacity",
        "name": "Capacity",
        "type": "text",
        "items": [
          {
            "displayValue": "256G",
            "value": "256G",
            "id": "256G"
          },
          {
            "displayValue": "512G",
            "value": "512G",
            "id": "512G"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

But I am receiving the wrong attributes. You can look at attributes items. They are different.

```
{
"category": {
   "name": "all",
   "products": [
    .....,
      {
        "id": "apple-imac-2021",
        ......
        "attributes": [
          {
            "id": "Capacity",
            "name": "Capacity",
            "type": "text",
            "items": [
              {
                "displayValue": "512G",
                "value": "512G",
                "id": "512G"
              },
              {
                "displayValue": "1T",
                "value": "1T",
                "id": "1T"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
    
      },...
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I go to the Network tab and see the response object everything is right, I am getting the right attributes. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by disabling the default cache when calling the request.

```
const { data } = await client.query({
            query: categoryQuery,
            variables: {
            title: category
           }
        }, {
           fetchPolicy: "no-cache" 
        })
```

for more detailed information:https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics